# Simple project management tool

Tags: visual-studio, svn, project-management, task-management

I use TFS at work which I am quite famililar with, I need a simple version of something similar that integrates into VS for my home hobby projects.

The only things I really need is :

- Task lists, with detail pages where I can record info about how I might implement the task / test it.
- Categorisation, prioritisation.
- SVN / VS support so I can commit to SVN at the same time referencing the task.

I have tried using notepad and the tasks in VS but thats just too mimimal. And other solutions that cater for full agile/scrum are OTT.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft now provide "[Visual Studio Team Services](http://www.visualstudio.com/products/visual-studio-online-overview-vs)" (it was first released under the name "Team Foundation Service" and later renamed to "Visual Studio Online" and then renamed again recently). It provides most (perhaps all) of the facilities of TFS but in the cloud; actually in Azure which is Microsoft's own cloud. The system is free for up to five users.

Comment: Seems like just what I wanted.

Comment: Well, I feel I have to add this: Visual Studio Online is awesome **but** the process templates aren't very convenient for small private projects that just needs a simple project management. At least imho.

Answer (score 1):

- Local [Mantis BT](http://www.mantisbt.org/) (it's mainly bugtracker, but can be configured and used as to-do list|planner) with [TortoiseMantis](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tortoisemantis/)
- Hosted [Assembla](https://www.assembla.com/plans) (free) Space

Answer (score 0):

You could try Trac and put all your tasks in those Trac tickets. The SVN cross-linking is excellent. First, have a look at the [Trac playground](http://trac.edgewall.org/demo-1.0) to test it. If it makes you happy, there is a good Windows bundle called [Bitnami Trac](http://bitnami.com/stack/trac) including all necessary tools, and it's for free and easy to install. Also check out the [Trac homepage](http://trac.edgewall.org).